# ¿Cómo convertir parte decimal de un numero a entera? en C

Tags: c

He conseguido separar la parte entera y decimal de un número double en c, pero quiero convertir la parte decimal a entero, ejemplo:

```
numero = 123.34
parte entera = 123
parte decimal = 34
```

y lo que entiendo hasta ahora es que para convertirla necesito multiplicar la parte decimal por 10, ejemplo:

```
.34 * 10 = 3.4
3.4 * 10 = 34
```

pero, ¿cómo puedo detener el bucle while en mi código?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(){

    double numero_flotante;
    int entero_numero_flotante;

    printf("Ingresa tu numero: ");
    scanf("%lf", &numero_flotante);
    entero_numero_flotante = numero_flotante; //SACAR EL NUMERO ENTERO DEL FLOTANTE
    numero_flotante = numero_flotante - entero_numero_flotante;//SACAR LA PARTE DECIMAL DEL FLOTANTE

    printf("parte entera: %d\n", entero_numero_flotante);
    printf("parte decimal: %lf\n\n", numero_flotante);

    while(1){
        printf("%lf\n", numero_flotante);
        numero_flotante = numero_flotante * 10;
        Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El bucle while se detendra depende al valor de n, el numero n debe ir disminuyendo y condicionado a que sea mayor a 0.

```
int numeroConvertido=0;
while(n>0){
        numeroConvertido+= (n%10) * 10;
        n=n/10;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví con [la respuesta de x-rw](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151880/127). Publico el código completo por si a alguien le sirve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(){

    double numero_flotante;
    int entero_numero_flotante ,n;
    printf("Ingresa tu numero: ");
    scanf("%lf", &numero_flotante);
    entero_numero_flotante = numero_flotante; //SACAR EL NUMERO ENTERO DEL FLOTANTE
    numero_flotante = numero_flotante - entero_numero_flotante;//SACAR LA PARTE DECIMAL DEL FLOTANTE

    printf("parte entera: %d\n", entero_numero_flotante);
    printf("parte decimal: %lf\n\n", numero_flotante);

    while(n > 0){

        printf("%lf\n", numero_flotante);
        numero_flotante = numero_flotante * 10;
        n = numero_flotante;
        numero_flotante = numero_flotante -n;
        printf("%d\n", n);

      }
}
```